# IntelliSense doesn't work for files in Public folder in Node.js solution in VS 2015

Tags: javascript, express, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, ntvs

I have Node.js Tools for Visual Studio (NTVS) and am developing an Express 4 application in Visual Studio. I added some JavaScript files to "public" folder. Sadly, for some reason the IntelliSense is not working for those JavaScript files. IntelliSense works in files placed in other directories in the same solution.

To clarify, nothing happens if I hit Ctrl+Space to invoke IntelliSense in JavaScript files in public folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that those files were not "Included in the Project". I noticed the dotted icons in Solution Explorer and added those to the project `[right click over those folders/files and select "include in project"].` This fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, you can mark it as answer and that will help community members to easier confirm this useful information :)